# Swift: section header XIB files aren't anchoring to tableView's width

Tags: swift, uitableview, xib

I have a tableView inside a UIViewController that has multiple sections. To create the custom section headers, I created them in a XIB file, while the custom cell is created in storyboard. The problem I'm running into is that the custom section headers aren't anchoring to the right of the tableView, unlike the custom cell. I tried setting the width in the viewForHeaderInSection in case .AddSection, but that doesn't work.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    switch CompAnalysisSection.init(rawValue: section) {
    case .CompetitorSection:
        let headerView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CompHeaderView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CompHeaderView

        return headerView
    case .AddSection:
        let headerView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AddCompsView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CompHeaderView
        headerView.frame.size.width = self.tableView.bounds.width
        headerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: tableView.frame.size.width).isActive = true

        headerView.delegate = self
        return headerView
    case .AverageSection:       
        let headerView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("AveragePeersView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CompHeaderView


        return headerView
    default: return UIView()
    }



class CompHeaderView: UIView {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
```

}

Image of what it looks like. As you can see, the sections are actually the first 3 rows that you see and the last row is a custom cell.

[image]

Comment: Add your code for `headerView` in this.

Comment: It's the CompHeaderView. I have nothing in there. Just that.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The autoresizing wasn't anchored to the left, and I didn't set it to expand. This is what's so frustrating about using storyboard or Xib lol.

[image]